# See how query looks after bind_param()

Tags: php, mysql

I have some function with this part of code:

```
$query = "some query";
$prod = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
$prod->bind_param("sss", $a,$b,$c) 
// my function have more than 15 bind values, and 2,3 sub queries
// so no point to write it here, I will solve error by myself later (I hope so)
$prod->execute();
```

This is standard OO mysql call and it works, almost always. I have 10.000 product which are inserted in this function, and always breaks on around 50 values ( 9.950 successful ).

Query looks fine, but I want to see how query looks before `execute` and after `bind_param`.

Comment: You can't; you create a prepared statement at the database, and then send the parameter values alone.

Comment: You could look into your database-bin-log or something like that.